# How to add literal strings in a DateTime format?

Tags: c#, datetime, format, culture

Is it possible to add the word "at" between a Date and Time format? I tried to add it just like this "dddd, d MMM, yyyy **at** HH:mm" but the webapp is tranforming it into "aA" or "aP" depending of regional configuration CA or AU

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, d MMM, yyyy at HH:mm"));
```

I forgot to say. I must be as a format string and no complex or concat functions.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, you need to escape the word by putting it in `'` marks `dddd, d MMM, yyyy 'at' HH:mm`

[Custom DateTime string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: The link also shows that "t" will be replaced with AM/PM, explaining the initial results.

Comment: +1 The link also shows that Google can find you the answer very quickly... ;)

Answer (score 24):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, d MMM, yyyy 'at' HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Improving @DaveDev answer using C# 6's String Interpolation

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine($"{now:dddd, d MMM, yyyy} at {now:HH:mm}");
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are far better, but:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;

var str = now.ToString("d MMM yyyy") + " at " + now.ToString("HH:mm");
```

or closer to your formatting:

```
var str = now.ToString("dddd, d MMM, yyyy") + " at " + now.ToString("HH:mm");
```