# Literal strings in a DateTime format

Tags: c#, datetime, format

I searched SO to find the answer to this issue, and found ["How to add literal strings in a DateTime format?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163725/how-to-add-literal-strings-in-a-datetime-format).

I tried the accepted solution, but did not get the result that I expected.  My code is below:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("'Previously exported on' d 'at' t")` which returns "Previously exported on 7 at P"

I had expected it to return "Previously exported on 02/07/2014 at 05:46 PM"

I also tried:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("'Previously exported on' f")` which returns "Previously exported on 0"

However, if I only use the simple format strings, I get the expected results:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("d")` returns "02/07/2014"
`DateTime.Now.ToString("t")` returns "05:46 PM"
`DateTime.Now.ToString("f")` returns "Friday, February 07, 2014 05:46 PM"

What am I missing?  Can the "short" format string NOT be used with the literals?

Comment: You got what you asked for.  Today is the 7th and for some reason you only like one letter of the am/pm indicator.  You didn't say what you *really* wanted so this is right now just as a guessing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this, which allows you to specify the format at each index using `{ index[,alignment][ :formatString] }`.  Ie,

```
string.Format("Previously exported on {0:d} at {0:t}", DateTime.Now);
```

---

It looks like the overloaded [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects either standard or custom DateTime format string -- it can't accommodate both.

> The format parameter should contain either a single format specifier character (see Standard Date and Time Format Strings) or a custom format pattern (see Custom Date and Time Format Strings) that defines the format of the returned string